# Error al agregar criterio de búsqueda WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, busqueda

En el siguiente codigo si saco el criterio de busqueda where y por ende la lieçne del bindParam anda perfecto pero no me filtraria las busqueda y me mostraria todos los datos nose cual es el error pero la pagina no anda y muestra

Esta página no funcionavln.com.ar te redireccionó demasiadas veces.
Intenta borrar tus cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
y ya probe borrando la cache.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucione, el error estaba en que generaba un bucle infinito de re direccionamiento en otra parte de mi código.

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente en las consultas las variables que agregas en ella van dentro de comillas simples, aparte de las comillas dobles que encierran toda la consulta. Prueba con esto...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM device WHERE id_user_device = ':id_user'";
```

Comment: No funciono igual muchas gracias.

Comment: `:id_user` no es una variable si no un placeholder, te recomiendo cheques sobre consultas preparadas en PHP con PDO y MySQLi y no llevan comillas